# C#: How much RAM does an object with all sub-objects need? Get list of needed RAM for object?

Tags: c#, .net

is there a way to get, for debuging purpose, a list of needed RAM for all my objects incl. sub-objects and so on, written to a text-file?

I need to get these values while running in production mode without visual studio running. For example every x minutes. Is this possible? How can I do that?

Thank you very much in advance,

Chris

Comment: serialize and look at the no. of bytes.

Comment: Not all objects are serializable.

Comment: have you looked at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A362781C-3870-43BE-8926-862B40AA0CD0&displaylang=en, http://memprofiler.com/ and http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm

Comment: @Zaki plus serialization includes information not present in the object itself - so will likely be an inflation of the actual size.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking. Remember, RAM is only necessary to store the *working set* of the process, not all the *memory* of the process; the memory that is not in the working set can be on disk. Are you worried about working set or about use of virtual address space?

Comment: I am interested in the sum of bytes my object needs (inclusive sub-objects). Let's say I have an object with 10 longs (80 bytes) and 10 bytes (10 bytes). Together this object needs 80 bytes. But when this object has sub-objects, then the value could be more because of storing pointers and so on. This complete value inclusive sub objects is the value I am searching for.

Comment: @Chris: I understand that. What I don't understand is *what you are trying to optimize for*. Suppose you find out that your objects need one million bytes altogether. What good does that do you?  That doesn't tell you how much virtual address space you need. It doesn't tell you how big your working set is. It doesn't tell you what the cost of a second-generation garbage collection is. That information tells you almost nothing useful, so I'm wondering why you care about it.

Comment: Sorry, I have not seen your comment. I got a memory leak, but only in production mode (not when I am running in debug/visual studio environment). I have no way to install any debug software in production environment, so I wanted to dump every x minutes the memory usage to see what (which object) gets bigger with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JetBrains DotTrace to do the memory profiling. Its only 30 days trial but what a great tool to navigate through specific in-memory objects.

Answer (score 2):

Load windbg and load  [sos.dll](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024041713/http://geekswithblogs.net/.NETonMyMind/archive/2006/03/14/72262.aspx), and attach to process.

log the output to a file
then do a `!DumpHeap -stat` (and variants)

[psscor2.dll](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/site/silentsignin?returnUrl=https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us?dg=microsoft.public.windbg&tid=efb95e74-d5f1-46a6-b584-64e65ebd0a7a&p=1) can dump the heap to an xml file. (or one for use with ClrProfiler)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tool, that will monitor size of process.
Or do this in seperate thread of running application.
Process.GetProcessesByName()...

Comment: But I need the memory on a per object basis, not the whole process. For example object a (containing b and c) is using 200MB, b is using 150MB and c is using 50MB.

Answer (score 0):

For value types, you should be able to use sizeof(). I don't think there is an equivalent for reference types, though. Note you can only use sizeof() inside an unsafe block.